# How to calculate the power of an asynchronous generator?

Tags: power, motor, generator

Let's have an asynchronous motor spinning unloaded, and another coupled to the main shaft currently not driven.

The motor will reach a speed which is below the synchronous speed (slip). If we force the shaft to spin via the other motor faster than this, the motor turns into generator mode.

What is the relation between the motor parameters and the available electrical output power in this setup as a function of shaft RPM?

By other means, how much torque and speed change is required from the input motor to feed a reference load on the output motor?

*As far as I know asynchrounous induction motor won't provide reactive power, let's put this problem aside.*

Comment: Of course the power returned to grid via the generator (Motor 1) will always be less than the power consumed from the grid by VFD + Motor 2.

Comment: @user_1818839 that's certainly right :)

Comment: What is this "main shaft", what speed is it at under the given conditions?
 Induction does indeed provide reactive power, only inductive AFAIK; see https://www.researchgate.net/figure/b-Reactive-power-slip-characteristic-of-induction-machine_fig2_304510611 for example.  
AFAIK, the curve is symmetrical around sync RPM: https://ecstudiosystems.com/discover/textbooks/lessons/AC/images/chapter13/02476.png

Comment: I don't think there's enough information provided to be able to help with answering this. Can you provide a diagram of the system that you have in mind?